# How is の方 used in それより公安の方は?

Tags: comparative-constructions

> A: [金]{かね}は？
> B: いつもの[通]{とお}りだ。それより[公安]{こうあん}の[方]{ほう}は？
> A: 心配するな。 私がついている。

> A: The money?
> B: Planned as always. Aside from that, public safety の方は？
> A: Don't worry. We're with you.

I'm not understanding what the の方は？ is doing. Or what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: I would translate that as "How about public safety?" (although perhaps a little more context would help...). の方 generally is attached to something you're comparing to something previously mentioned, I think.

Comment: 「公安」は「警視庁公安部（http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AD%A6%E8%A6%96%E5%BA%81%E5%85%AC%E5%AE%89%E9%83%A8）です

Comment: I thought that as well, but didn't know that you could be sure it was talking about the public safety department rather than the concept of public safety, from the given context. (It does make much more sense when talking about the department though.)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie ですね～AさんもBさんも明らかに「悪い人/[悪役]{あくやく}」だから、public safetyなんか心配しないでしょうね～^^

Comment: A「[金]{きん/キム}さんは元気？」B「いつも通りだ。それより[公安]{きみやす}くんの方は？」A「心配するな。公安には私がついている。」

Answer (score 6, accepted):

の[方]{ほう} is just a way of emphasizing "about".

> Apart from that, what about the public safety department?

Literally, it means "direction". A similar way of saying Xの方 in English would be with "on the X side of things", i.e.

> Apart from that, what about the public safety department side of things?

P.S. There was a [similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/%E6%96%B9-also-read-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86-when-referring-to-a-person) where the OP confused の[方]{ほう} with の[方]{かた}, which is grammatically viable (replace a noun with another noun), but doesn't make as much sense here.