# Need help with 1 sentence [MC and his secretary. She said this while Mc's complaining about being the next leader of his prestigious family]

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english

Context: MC is about to become the new head of his family ,which has been governing 1 big land for many generations .He complains to his secretary that's it's hard and feels like he isn't ready for this important task (his father had retired ).

Then his secretary said : **「執務の方は順次で結構ですので」**>> much thanks if anyone can explain for me the meaning of this sentence.

More context below :
跡継ぎ息子に生まれたからには、いつかこの時が来るのは覚悟していた。​

MC「僕が当主……だけど……ちょっと早すぎるよね……」

Secretary「そうでしょうか？お父上様はアシュトン様と同じ歳の頃に当主になったそうですよ」

MC「簡単に言ってくれるけどさぁ……」

以来、キングスワース家は代々この土地を治めている。その家を継ぐわけだから、プレッシャーは想像以上だ。

**Secretary「執務の方は順次で結構ですので」 (>>> I don't understand this sentence )**

Secretary「慣れるまでは私がサポートしますから、ご安心ください」

Comment: You already got a nice answer, but here's another reference: [11712/How is の方 used in それより公安の方は?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11712/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, の方 is an expression that is used to single out a specific aspect in contrast to others. In English, it would be equivalent to saying "As for...". For example, you could be chatting with someone about life in general, and then change the topic by saying 仕事の方は...

Here, 執務の方 indicates that the following part of the sentence/conversation is intended to be about 執務, *as opposed to* other aspects/responsibilities/implications of being the new head.

Next, (condition/status)で結構 is a common polite phrase for stating that the said condition or status is sufficient or good enough. For example, 電話で結構です (just dropping a call would be fine) or それで結構です (that would be fine).

Here, 順次で結構です can be understood as 順次 would be fine. 順次 means to follow a sequential order. Although not explicit, you can understand this to mean "to follow (slowly), or step by step, as opposed to doing it all in one go". If it's hard to understand, looking at it together with the last sentence might help.

Finally, the speaker omits the rest of the sentence (i.e. the consequence) with the (reason)-で style. If you had to imagine one in, it could be something alone the line of ご安心ください, which the speaker says in the next sentence anyway after adding some more detail.

Comment: thank you for your detail breakdown