# The meaning of の in this sentence: 私の方こそ聞きたいですね

Tags: grammar, particle-の, relational-nouns

私の means my? So why does it appear in this sentence?

> 私**の**方こそ聞きたいですね

Which translates to 'How? That's what I'd like to know.'
Can Someone please give me a break down of this sentence？

Thank you :)

Comment: How do you read 方? Please take a look at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11023/1628 (and the comments on the answer). Does this help?

Comment: `translates to 'How? That's what I'd like to know.'` -- Where did you get the translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 方 in the noun phrase "Xの方" designates X as a "side" involved in a given matter or event. It is used to highlight the division of a matter/event between its participants, and picks out particular one of them.

So in「私の方こそ聞きたいですね」, "私の方" picks out "私" (as the subject of the sentence) from among the participants/sides, with the event in question being the present conversation.

The sentence says it is 私, not other participant(s)/side(s) in the conversation -- namely, "you", presumably -- who should want to ask the question (whatever that is). Translation:

> That's what *I* would like to ask. (with emphasis on "I")

Here the の is the genitive particle: "私"→"I"; "私の" → "my"; 私の方→"my side"